# PHP REGEX: Get domain from URL

Tags: php, regex, url, dns

**What I want**

---

I want to get from a `URL` the `domain` part so from `http://example.com/` -> `example.com`

**Examples:**

---

```
+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| input                                        | output                |
+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask   | www.stackoverflow.com |
| http://validator.w3.org/check                | validator.w3.org      |
| http://www.google.com/?q=hello               | www.google.com        |
| http://google.de/?q=hello                    | google.de             |
+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

I found some related questions in `stackoverflow` but none of them was exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This code will help you get the complete domain name: https://gist.github.com/praisedpk/64bdb80d28144aa78d58469324432277

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There's no need to use a regex for this. PHP has an inbuilt function to do just this. Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: it good only if containing http(s) , not for "stackoverflow.com/questions"

Comment: this will also give you subdomains. Be careful because `parse_url('http://example.com', PHP_URL_HOST) == parse_url('http://www.example.com', PHP_URL_HOST)` will return false

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
$domain = parse_url('http://' . str_replace(array('https://', 'http://'), '', $url), PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Because `parse_url` doesn't return host key when schema is missing in `$url`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$tmp = parse_url($url);
$url = $tmp['host']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is like the [regex from theraccoonbear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442333/php-regex-get-domain-from-url/3442377#3442377) but with support for HTTPS domains.

```
if (preg_match('/https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\//i', $target_string, $matches)) {
  $domain = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumes that `http://` prefixes everything.

```
$tmp = explode("/", $url);
$domain = $tmp[2];
```

Comment: heh, most out-of-the-box solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following regexp might answers your question.

[This diagram](https://regexper.com/#.*%5C%2F%5C%2F%28%5B%5E%5C%2F%3A%5D%2B%29.*) explains how it works, or rather why it works :-)

```
$regexp = '/.*\/\/([^\/:]+).*/';

// www.stackoverflow.com
echo preg_replace($regexp, '$1', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');

// google.de
echo preg_replace($regexp, '$1', 'http://google.de/?q=hello');

// it works for the other input tests too ;-)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick and dirty solution.

`http://([^/]+).*`

I haven't tested it, but it should grab anything between the `http://` and the first slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/http:\/\/([^\/]+)\//i', $target_string, $matches)) {
  $domain = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Best way i think:

```
preg_match('/(http(|s)):\/\/(.*?)\//si',  'http://www.example.com/page/?bla=123#!@#$%^&*()_+', $output);
// $output[0] ------------>  https://www.example.com/
```