# Select only the main url in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP REGEX: Get domain from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442333/php-regex-get-domain-from-url)

I am working on a project and it need to select only main url such as
from http://domain.com/link/project/domain/index.php i need to select only [domain.com](http://domain.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more general use case you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/link/project/domain/index.php';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
var_dump($parsed['host']); // domain.com
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)); // same
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I am storing links and it is not on my server

Comment: Then you should use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442333/php-regex-get-domain-from-url

Answer (score -1):

```
$myurl = "http://domain.com/link/project/domain/index.php"; 

    // get domain name 
    preg_match("/^(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i", $myurl, $domain_only); 
    $host = $domain_only[2]; 
    echo "Domain Name is:  " . $host;
```

Comment: You are right! Thx Kaii!

Comment: Is there any reason to reinvent the wheel when a built-in function exists to do exactly this?