# PHP - Echo array value foreach array count

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code

```
$businessWebsite = 'http://www.times.hello.com.uk/articles/view/20.141013/local/police-killer.gets-10-more-months-over-drugs.539550';
$host = parse_url($businessWebsite, PHP_URL_HOST );
$parts = explode( '.', $host);
//$parts = array_reverse( $parts );

$domain = $parts[1].'.'.$parts[2].'.'.$parts[3].'.'.$parts[4];

print_r($parts);

echo $domain;
```

This echo's `times.hello.com.uk` this is made up of four parts

```
Array
(
    [0] => www
    [1] => times
    [2] => hello
    [3] => com
    [4] => uk
)
```

Let us say my domain is     `$businessWebsite = 'http://www.times.com.uk/articles/view/20.141013/local/police-killer.gets-10-more-months-over-drugs.539550';`

It would echo `times.hello.com..` I would end up with two dots at the end.

If the domain is `$businessWebsite = 'http://www.times.com/articles/view/20.141013/local/police-killer.gets-10-more-months-over-drugs.539550';`

It would echo `times.com...` I would end up with three dots at the end.

How do I go solving the problem?

I want to remove the double and triple dots at the end.

Comment: What's your problem ?

Comment: I want to remove the double and triple dots at the end.

Comment: Stop assuming that $parts[3] and $parts[4] actually exist, and actually check if they exist.... if they don't, don't echo them or the '.'.... why not use array_slice() to extract the parts of the array that you want to display (`$parts = str_slice(explode( '.', $host), 1);`), then implode with a '.' to create a single string that you can then echo

Comment: if you need get domain from any URL, you can use REGEX:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442333/php-regex-get-domain-from-url

Comment: @Thiago256 The accepted answer on that question suggests using `parse_url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's `trim` and `implode`.

As you said you want to remove double and triple dots at the end of the string:

```
$domain = implode('.',$parts);

$domain = trim($domain, '.');

print $domain;
```

Comment: For that: 
`if($parts[0] == "www") { 
    unset($parts[0]);
}

`

Comment: After that you can implode it and trim it. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @user2333968 Thanks. Please tick mark the answer if its correct.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at phps [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

This allows to do something like this:

```
echo implode('.', $parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an `implode` method:

```
$domain = implode('.',$parts);
```

You can remove the first item of parts prior to imploding:

```
array_shift($parts);
```